# broken html element causing submit button to not show

Tags: html, input, syntax, tags

well I have no clue what's happening so I will just show it to you via jpg:

[image]

I don't even know what to call this type of error... but because the tag is broken the submit button doesn't show. But I have duplicated this type of code before and never a problem like this... so strange. I'm using Notepadd++ v 6.1.3 (UNICODE) to code. Can anyone explain this to me, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Paste the actual source code here. I think you have an unclosed `"` or `>` in the line above starting `<input size="3" ...`

Comment: oh wow, I am blind as a bat, that was the first thing I checked but I guess I just didn't see it. It's official, I now need glasses. Coding has taken its toll I suppose.

Comment: Oh i spoke too soon. still broken.

Comment: Let's see the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds weird, but could you have "smart quotes" (the curvy ones that MS Word gives you) instead of normal quotes?  Notepadd++ may not show them differently, but they might not be interpreted as normal quotes.

BTW, this is just a guess.

Comment: Good guess. Smart quotes show as such in Notepad++. They are easy to distinguish from regular quotes.

Comment: Ones darker than the other. Im going with smart quotes.

Comment: Notepad++ makes it darker. It's a feature of the software. What's actually happening is Notepad++ is coloring purple the "pairs" of quotation marks (starting and ending). It's black because there is no mate to pair with.

Comment: Ah I got it, it was a unpaired quotation mark. The code I was checking was essentially page width so i can see it all just scroolling up and down, after really examing all my dimensions I saw another line of code was very far off to the right, must have leaned on the space bar or something, maybe I dosed off for a second, lol.

Comment: mark this thread as one for the blooper reel guys, hahaha. But thanks for letting me know about the other type of quotation, I will keep that in mind next time I encounter this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to see from what you posted I recommend you use code blocks

But looking at the color of the text and what I can see from your screen shot it seems you did not close you input tag  You probably have something like this

```
<input size = "3" type = "text" name = "quantity" value = "something"
```

where you did not end the input tag or you have something like

```
<input size = "3" type = "text" name = "quantity" value = "something>
                                                          <!-- ^^^^^^ INSERT "-->
```

where you did not put the ending " so it is seeing the text after it as a string.

What you need to put in for the correct code would be

```
<input size = "3" type = "text" name = "quantity" value = "something">
```

Then the line under it will work.

I'm sure this is your problem hope this helped :)